# React Redux: Delay between component inner content while updating

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component that have 2 components inside of it:

```
MyComp {
    render ( 
       html of My Comp..
       <Loading show={this.props.isLoading}/>
       <ErrorMessage show={this.props.hasError}/>  
    )
}
```

When it is receiving data, it shows the Loading.
When the loading is complete, it receive something like:

```
{
   isLoading: false,
   hasError: true
}
```

But in screen, the loading close like 2s before the hasError displays.

Both components are built in the same strategie:

```
class Loading extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state =  {isLoading : props.show};
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({ isLoading: nextProps.show });
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
          return (
            <div className="loading">
              <div className="loading-message">
              Carregando...
              </div>
            </div>);
        }
        return ('');
    }
}

export default Loading;
```

Comment: just wondering, why are you using a local `state`? why not read directly from `this.props` instead of trying to sync local `state` with external `props`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer for this issue, as i can't be sure where the delay can come from.

But according to your code i would suggest to not use a local `state` and try to [sync it with external `props`](https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e).
This can lead to bugs (maybe related to your issue?) as `componentWillReceiveProps` can get invoked even when no new `props` received, beside it is in [deprecation process](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) since react V16.2.

Instead i would just read directly from `this.props`:

```
class Loading extends Component {

    render() {
        if (this.props.isLoading) {
          return (
            <div className="loading">
              <div className="loading-message">
              Carregando...
              </div>
            </div>);
        }
        return ('');
    }
}
```

Again, not sure it is directly related to your issue but it is a better practice.